# Scaling/Rezise in Blender 2.8 Python/Script not working on mesh

Tags: python, mesh, vertices, faces, scale

I am working on a scrip that makes tiles (like for a kitchen floor). I have a script that works perfect on planes for 4 sided tiles. However, I am running into an issues on non-4 sided tiles.

I chose to use cylinders which almost exactly works as needed. But I am hitting an issue on "beveling" (which is just scaling 1 of the faces) the top face of the cylinder.

My code looks at all the faces on the mesh, and

-if it does equal 4 sides, then the script deselects them.

-If it does not equal 4 sides, then runs another check

-If we haven't deleted any faces yet, then it deletes 1 face

-If we have deleted 1 face, then we are on the top face
**Up to this point works perfectly together**

-Then the script scales in the selected face
**This is where it causes issues**

The scaling code works fine on its own if I manually select a face first, and also works fine by hand. I'm not sure if it's a bug or something I'm missing but I could use any help my fellow blender scripters can offer.

I'm including just the face adjusting part of the script, so to test my code you'll have to Add > Mesh > Cylinder to test it out.

Thank you!
(see code and images below)
[image: Selecting A Cylinder Face in Python]
[image: Scaling A Cylinder Face in Python]
[image: Selecting A Cylinder Vertices in Python]
[image: Scaling A Cylinder Vertices in Python]

```
#Import Python
import bpy
#Import mesh handling
import bmesh
#Import vector
from mathutils import Vector


tileBevelZ = 0.85

#_________________________________________Delete the bottom face

#edit mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode   = 'EDIT'   )

#number of faces we've deleted
facesDeleted = 0
#our current object
obj = bpy.context.object
#ref to mesh
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)


#for each face in mesh
for f in bm.faces:
    #if it's selected
    if f.select == True:
        #if it does not have the number of sides we want
        if len(f.verts) == 4:
            #we dont want to select it
            f.select = False
        # else if it does have the same number of sides    
        else:
            #if we have not deleted a side yet
            if facesDeleted == 0:
                #deslect 1 of the faces
                f.select = False
                #increase faces deleted
                facesDeleted += 1
            #else if we increased our counter    
            else:
                #make sure it's selected
                f.select = True
                #Delete the face
                bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='FACE')

#set mode to faces
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode( type  = 'FACE'   )
#select all                
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')

#_________________________________________Adjust scale of top face for bevel            
#for each face in mesh
for f in bm.faces:
    #if it's selected
    if f.select == True:
        #if it does not have the number of sides we want
        if len(f.verts) == 4:
            #we dont want to select it
            f.select = False
        # else if it does have the same number of sides    
        else:
            #make sure it's selected
            f.select = True
            #set mode to vertices
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode( type  = 'FACE'   )
            #Scale the face in
            bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(tileBevelZ , tileBevelZ , tileBevelZ), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Another take on getting the result.**

*Rather than trying to debug what is happening with your question script here is another take to achieve what I believe is the desired result.*

Test script, object mode, adds a cylinder, removes bottom face, scales top face.

Bottom and top faces have z component to their normals. This is how they are selected below.

Once selected, the bottom face is removed from the faces collection.

Scaling top face similar to  related question  [Using python and bmesh to scale/resize a face in place](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121123/using-python-and-bmesh-to-scale-resize-a-face-in-place) , in this case,  using `bmesh.ops.scale`

Notice apart from adding the cylinder to test, there is no `bpy.ops` used.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix

scale_factor = 0.85

# add a cylinder to test

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add()
ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)

top_face = [f for f in bm.faces if f.normal.z > 0.5].pop()

bottom_face = [f for f in bm.faces if f.normal.z < 0.5].pop()

# remove bottom face

bm.faces.remove(bottom_face)

# scale top face 

bmesh.ops.scale(bm,
        vec = (scale_factor,) * 3,
        space = Matrix.Translation(-top_face.calc_center_median()),
        verts = top_face.verts)

bm.to_mesh(me)
me.update()
```

Note `bmesh.ops.create_cone(diameter1=1, diameter2=0.85)` could be used to create the shape, removing the need to scale.

Suggestion, don't over comment code, and consider using `if f.select:` instead of `if f.select == True:`

Comment: Thank you. This is a very elegant solution. I just tested the script and it worked as needed.

I did do a workaround in the meantime where I do an inset and just raise that a little. Having the extra edge loop doesn't affect my needs, though I will be using this.

Can I ask, 

 I'm new to python and blender and comment code so I can easily go back and reference things I'm unfamiliar with. Is there a reason you suggest to limit that/ Performance perhaps?

Comment: my understanding is DRY vs WET code is about personal preference. Since I work with a team of people of various skill levels, I feel it would be more appropriate to have even small explanations for those who either forgot or have never touched python before. And I haven't found anything on performance impacts.. I know other engines remove comments during runtime, but I could see that as a potential downside. Please let me know if there are others or this is just your preference.

Comment: IMHO Commenting every line is a wee bit OTT.  Drowning in comments to a point where one can't see the wood for the trees, eg  In  question code the `# set mode to vertices` comment is followed by setting selection mode to face.  Have some faith in your team members, that even the least experienced can decipher a simple import or increment a counter code line without it requiring comment.  Anyway each to there own and sure it is a matter of personal preference.  Remember it is only a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! That was well explained