# Cannot flip normals in python with `flip()`

Tags: python, normals

I want to flip the normals via python. I have a single polygon as an object loaded. I am using blender 3.4.1.

[image]

I try to do the following in python:

```
>>> bpy.data.meshes['Plane'].polygons[0].normal
Vector((0.0, 0.0, 1.0))    
>>> bpy.data.meshes['Plane'].polygons[0].flip()
>>> bpy.data.meshes['Plane'].polygons[0].normal
Vector((-0.0, 0.0, -1.0))
```

After executing this, the normals in the viewport did not change. Often I see the command `normal_flip` being used which seems to be not in the scope of the object I work with:

```
>>> bpy.data.meshes['Plane'].polygons[0].normal_flip()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MeshPolygon' object has no attribute 'normal_flip'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Flip normals on a selection

If you do a Flip Normals with <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> and look at the Info Editor, you will see that the only output done is:

```py
bpy.ops.mesh.flip_normals()
```

All you have to run is this. Though I would also put this inside a check for selection first, because it works only on a selection yet will run with no error nor feedback of whether it did something or not, even with nothing selected.

```py
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

if any (f.select for f in bm.faces):
    print("Flipping Normals")
    bpy.ops.mesh.flip_normals()

    
else:
    print("Nothin selected to flip normals.")
```

## Flip selection on a specific polygon index independently of selection

`normal_flip()` is part of bmesh, here's hot to use it on a specific face:

```py
import bpy
import bmesh

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)
me = bpy.context.object.data

bm.faces[0].normal_flip()

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

To learn more:

[mesh - Python: find faces with incorrect normals to flip and flip them - Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87113/53447)

[Scaling/Rezise in Blender 2.8 Python/Script not working on mesh - Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/157516/53447)

Comment: My actual case is a pretty complex mesh, with broken normals where I only have to treat only a subset of faces. If I use `mesh.flip_normals` I cannot differentiate unfortunately.

Comment: What about `Recalculate Normals` (Shift N)? `bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent(inside=False)`

Comment: Many have flipped by this. But still some are wrong it seems.

Comment: You can always select the problematic faces and run the above. But if you really want to write down the indexes of faces and treat them with normal_flip(), I'll edit that into my answer. Just a few minutes.

Comment: Yeah, they are quite a lot.