# Using python to scale/resize a selected groups of faces with individual origin

Tags: python, scale, bmesh

question based on this topic [Using python and bmesh to scale/resize a face in place](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121123/using-python-and-bmesh-to-scale-resize-a-face-in-place) where each face was scaled separately.

So actually the question in the title. I'm newbie to python. I tried to find connected faces based on the same vertex indexes, then calculate the average mean of the vertices positions included this faces(like a origin point).
But it works only for single group faces, how to make it for multiple group faces?

[image]

[image]

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import numpy as np
from mathutils import Vector as vec

#EDIT mode#
me = bpy.context.edit_object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
scale_factor = 0.5

seleted_vert_group = []
verts_co_x = []
verts_co_y = []
verts_co_z = []

#checking for matches
for face1 in bm.select_history:
    passwither = 0 #pass double matched face
    for face2 in bm.select_history:
        if face1 == face2:
            continue
        for vert1 in face1.verts: 
            for vert2 in face2.verts:
                if passwither == 1:
                    continue
                if vert1.index == vert2.index:
                    passwither = 1
                    print(f'face index: {face1.index}')
                    for vert in face1.verts:
                        seleted_vert_group.append(vert)
                        verts_co_x.append(vert.co.x)
                        verts_co_y.append(vert.co.y)
                        verts_co_z.append(vert.co.z)

co_x = np.sum(verts_co_x)/len(verts_co_x)
co_y = np.sum(verts_co_y)/len(verts_co_y)
co_z = np.sum(verts_co_z)/len(verts_co_z)
origin_point = vec((co_x,co_y,co_z))
 
for vert in set(seleted_vert_group):
    vert.co = origin_point + scale_factor * (vert.co - origin_point)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find connected islands**

[image]

- Tag all selected faces as false
- Pop one selected face tag as true
- Yield recursively to find all selected and connected faces (an island)
- Scale the verts of the island based on average vert loc. (Could use face centers instead)
- Remove the island from selected set

See image on how this may not work as expected for faces touching at vertex corners.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix

#EDIT mode#
me = bpy.context.edit_object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
scale_factor = 0.5

faces = set(f for f in bm.faces if f.select)

def walk_island(face):
    face.tag = True
    yield face
    faces = [f for e in face.edges for f in e.link_faces if not f.tag and f.select]
    for f in faces:
        yield from walk_island(f)

def scale(island):
    verts = set(v for f in island for v in f.verts)
    bmesh.ops.scale(
        bm,
        verts=list(verts),
        vec=(scale_factor,) * 3,
        space=Matrix.Translation(
            sum((-v.co for v in verts), Vector()) / len(verts)
            ))   

for f in faces:
    f.tag = False
    
while faces:
    f = faces.pop()
    island = set(walk_island(f))
    scale(island)
    faces -= island
    
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should move back them into first position.

I answered based on [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121123/using-python-and-bmesh-to-scale-resize-a-face-in-place)

[image]

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context


ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
scale_factor = 0.5

for face in bm.select_history:
        center = face.calc_center_median()
        for v in face.verts:
            v.co = center + scale_factor * (v.co - center)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Comment: The problem this method is that the connected edges will have a double scale