# Scaling down one face of a mesh using Python API

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh

I am generating a mesh from a collection of points read from a json file. That collection of points will define the vertices, and from them I will derive the faces of the final mesh

Code is working fine until I try to scale down just one of the faces. I have used the accepted answer of this question as a reference: [Using python and bmesh to scale/resize a face in place](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/121123/133985)

The problem is I don't know what is the criteria used in that answer to select the face to be scaled down, since the line `face = bm.select_history.active` looks very generic. Instead what I tried is to access the first face in the sequence of faces in the mesh with `face = bm.faces[0]`, but then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 88, in <module>
IndexError: BMElemSeq[index]: outdated internal index table, run ensure_lookup_table() first
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console


This is the script I wrote:

import bpy
import json
import bmesh
import os
    
# make collection
new_collection = bpy.data.collections.new('new_collection')

# Link object with collection
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(new_collection)

# Reading from a file a collection of points
with open(r'path\\vertices.json','r') as f: 
      j=json.load(f) 

vertices = j["vertices"]
faces = ... # here generating the faces from the vertices
edges = []
    
# Creating Mesh
new_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(str(country_name)+'_mesh')
new_mesh.from_pydata(vertices, edges, faces)

# Recalculating Normals for each face
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(new_mesh)
bmesh.ops.recalc_face_normals(bm, faces=bm.faces)
bm.to_mesh(new_mesh)
bm.free()

# Applying changes to the Mesh
new_mesh.update()
      
# Making object from mesh
new_object = bpy.data.objects.new(str(country_name)+'_object', new_mesh)

# add object to scene collection
new_collection.objects.link(new_object)

# Scaling one face
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(new_mesh)

scale_factor = 0.5
face = bm.faces[0]
if isinstance(face, bmesh.types.BMFace):
    c = face.calc_center_median()
    for v in face.verts:
        v.co = c + scale_factor * (v.co - c)

bm.to_mesh(new_mesh)
bm.free()

# Applying changes to the Mesh
new_mesh.update()
```

I also tried to select and resize the first face in the mesh like this:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.select_nth(nth=0)
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0.5, 0.5, 1))
```

But this approach triggers:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 91, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.mesh.select_nth.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

How can I select a single face as active to then scale it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
# Scaling one face
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(new_mesh)
```

with

```
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(new_mesh)
bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
```

to rid yourself of the first error. You only need the 3rd `ensure_lookup_table` for your specific problem. I've just put the other two in for completeness. That should allow your scale operations to work.

If your mesh isn't in edit mode, you'll need

```
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

before that fragment, although that assumes that you're working on the current active object.

Comment: Thanks Marty, I will try this approach and let you know

Comment: Thanks! works perfectly